# How to access C bitfield in Go

Tags: go, cgo

I have a struct like so:

```
typedef struct st_MASK_SETTINGS
{
  uint32_t foo  : 1;
  uint32_t bar  : 7;
} MASK_SETTINGS
```

Now through cgo I would like to access `foo` - but cannot find any documentation how to do so.

Naive `v := ms.foo` complains `has no field or method`.

Comment: I doubt you can: You probably have to do the bitfiddeling yourself.

Comment: But how (without writing more C code)?

Comment: @abergmeier: golang has bitwise operators too: https://yourbasic.org/golang/bitwise-operator-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Bitwise operators only help me once I have a field to access.

Comment: What is wrong with `ms & 0x80 != 0` and `ms & 0x7f` ?

Comment: To clarify - `ms` is an instance of `MASK_SETTINGS`. If I try to access it directly it is of type `_Ctype_struct_MASK_SETTINGS` and thus e.g. shifting not possible. I can of course write a C function, which combines `foo` and `bar` into a `uint32_t` and consume that value in Go. I was wondering whether there is any chance to consume bitfields withouth having to write C code. If that is not what you meant could you clarify please.

Answer (score 1):

Well you won't like this answer, but

1. there is no portable way to do this because bitfield packing is "implementation-defined" in both C and C++, and
2. bitfield support in Go seems fairly crappy (perhaps due to #1).

First of all, the layout of bitfields is implementation-defined in every existing C and C++ standard.  This means that none of the standards specify how bits in a bitfield definition should be packed (i.e., where they should go) -- it's totally up to the compiler.  You may find how they are laid out to be a certain way *in practice* given a few compiler samples, but you will be deep into undefined behavior territory.

We are working on this issue in gcc under [bug #83784](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83784) (and by "we" I mean Andrew Pinski), and I'm hoping that in gcc 10 or 11 we'll have an optimal solution.  To be clear, there is a solution now -- it is use a union and define pack and unpack functions to read each bitfield and manually put the data where it belongs in memory.  The issue is that when you have properly guessed the bit layout gcc uses then the function should become no-ops and "compile-away".  This is currently not happening.

Example:

```
union a {
    struct {
        int field1:12;
        int field2:20;
    };
    int packed;
};

static union a a_pack(union a a)
{
    union a ret = {0};

    ret.packed = (a.field1 & ((1 << 12) - 1) << 20;
    ret.packed |= a.field2 & ((1 << 20) - 1)

    return ret;
}

static union a a_unpack(union a a)
{
    union a ret = {0};

    ret.field1 = a.packed >> 20;
    ret.field2 = a.packed & ((1 << 20) - 1);

    return ret;
}
```

Once you do this, you can "pack" your bitfield, read a.packed from Go and then either bit fiddle it or use [one of the bitfield implementations](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/internal/gen/bitfield).

I told you you wouldn't like the answer. :)